# Android - Spinner: how to add small triangle on top of popup listview

Tags: android

how to add small triangle on top of popup listview

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`... popup listview` that's called a **Spinner**.

And the arrow is already part of it.
It indicates that it will open to a dialog with a list of options.
Which, in turn, is actually a ListView.